# Partial Fractions to solve Logistic Equation

Tags: dynamical-systems, partial-fractions

I am not really understanding how my book is getting

$$\frac{x'}{x(1-\frac{x}{K})}=\frac{x'}{x}+\frac{x'}{K-x}$$

so $$\frac{x'}{x(1-\frac{x}{K})}=\frac{x'}{x-\frac{x^2}{K}}$$
$$=\frac{\frac{x'}{1}}{\frac{xK-x^2}{K}}$$
$$=\frac{x'K}{xK-x^2}$$
$$=\frac{x'K}{x(K-x)}$$

The book said its "applying partial fractions", but I am confused about how they reached that answer

Comment: Before "so", this is the neat decomposition $$\frac1{x(1-x/K)}=\frac{K}{x(K-x)}=\frac{(K-x)+(x)}{x(K-x)}=\frac1x+\frac1{K-x}.$$ After "so", I do not understand anything anymore but surely, one does not "apply partial fractions", actually one seems to run in circles to prove that $A=A$.

Comment: oh ok...that makes sense. But I don't think I would have been able to see that by myself, just looking at the problem. Is there something that would tip me off that I should do something like this in future problems?

Comment: Yes, the words "partial fractions" and the formula at the beginning of your post (the only parts coming from the book, right?).

Comment: Yes those are the only parts, but I mean the words "partial fractions" were in the worked out solution. So it said, using partial fractions. But if this were a homework or exam problem I wouldn't have that little hint that told me to do this, so what are some other things that would suggest that this would be the right step to take? Because to me it seems kind of unnatural, like not something I would just think of immediately

Comment: Trying to reduce a fraction to simple elements should be something that comes to your mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do smething like this
$x'\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{K-x}\right)=x'\left(\frac{K-x+x}{x(K-x)}\right)$